# how to copy an excel file into a outlook folder

Tags: excel, vbscript, outlook, wsh

I'm trying to copy an excel file to an outlook folder.  I can find the outlook folder but I could not figure out how to copy the excel file there.

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objInbox = objNamespace.Folders("ServiceDesk Support")
Set colItems = objInbox.Items
sourcefolder = "c:\"
strfilename = "Online Status -Test.xlsx"
sourcefile = "C:\Online Status -Test.xlsx"
set strfile = fso.GetFolder(sourcefolder)

GetSubfolders(objInbox)

Sub GetSubfolders(objParentFolder)
    Set colFolders = objParentFolder.Folders
    For Each objFolder in colFolders
        Set objSubfolder = objParentFolder.Folders(objFolder.Name)
        if objSubfolder = "File Status" then
            set savefolder = objSubfolder
            fso.CopyFile sourcefile, objSubfolder.Name
        end if
        GetSubfolders objSubfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

The script completes successfully, but no file in the Outlook folder.

Comment: You don't save the file to outlook! Or add it to outlook somewhere in your code!

Comment: Oh well . Kinda thought that might be it. But my company drags the file to an Outlook folder and saves it there. So I thought I might try to automate the process.